# How to zip 'n' oldest files/dir in a dir in bash

Tags: bash

i have dir logs that contains 100 dirs. i need to zip (eg. logs_.zip) the oldest 75 dirs in logs dir. At any given time the logs dir should contain only latest 25 dirs and zip files of oldest 75 files

Comment: I think what you are really looking for is `logrotate`

Comment: wht is logrotate? pls explain

Comment: I know it doesn't answer exactly your question, but since it is a long explanation I put it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

From logrotate manual:

> LOGROTATE(8)
>   System Administrator's Manual
>   LOGROTATE(8)
>
> NAME
>          logrotate ‐ rotates, compresses, and mails system logs
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          logrotate [-dv] [-f|--force] [-s|--state file] config_file ..
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          logrotate  is designed to ease administration of systems that generate large numbers of log files.  It allows automatic rotation,
>   compression, removal, and mailing of log files.  Each log file may be
>          handled daily, weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large.
>
> Normally, logrotate is run as a daily cron job.  It will not modify a log more than once in one day unless the criterion for that
>   log is based on the log's size and logrotate is being run  more  than
>          once each day, or unless the -f or --force option is used.
>
> Any  number of config files may be given on the command line. Later config files may override the options given in earlier files, so
>   the order in which the logrotate config files are listed is impor‐
>          tant.  Normally, a single config file which includes any other config files which are needed should be used.  See below for more
>   information on how to use the include directive  to  accomplish  this.
>          If a directory is given on the command line, every file in that directory is used as a config file.
>
> If  no  command  line arguments are given, logrotate will print version and copyright information, along with a short usage summary. 
>   If any errors occur while rotating logs, logrotate will exit with
>          non-zero status.

Comment: thanks but i need to do it manually... as part of my bash script.. Eg. before i create a dir under logs dir i need to check the threshold (25) and zip the oldest 75 if needed..